# Result Interpretation of Tukey's Test Box Plot

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing

[image]

I have a question related to the interpretation of the result of Tukey's test box plot. I am attaching the two plots from the R graph gallery, which I am following. According to the Confidence level plot, only AC and DB are not significantly different.
So, the box plot will be both A and C of the same color and letter and DB of the same color and letter. It's a simple case.

My main confusions are considering a scenario where:

Group A I have letter displayed c and for group E I have letter bc and For group C I have b. So what does this letter combination bc means? Does it mean that A and E are not significantly different and E and C not significantly different? I was expecting the shared letter to be on top for example for E on top of b be c, but in my case, it's together and I am really confused.

Any help to understand how the compact letter display for Tukey's result boxplot functions is appreciated.

[image: I took reference from R -graph gallery Tukey Test and boxplot]

Comment: Attachment not visible.

Comment: Hi @BruceET, I edited the question again. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for making the figure visible. In the figure it is possible to resolve the population means into three distinct groups: A and C cannot be distinguished, B and D cannot be distinguished, and E can be distinguished from all of the others. However, such testing doesn/t always resolve so neatly. With 3 groups A, B, C, it might be clear that the population mean for C is smaller than the pop. mean for A. But, the _sample_ mean for B is btw the sample means for A and C, and it's not possible to say that B is significantly different from either A or C. Then plot for B gets double letters.

Comment: Hi Bruce. Thank you for the explanation. Is there any source that I can look at? I

Comment: If it's part of the question, this is just to spell out that a box plot usually shows medians, quartiles and extremes. It's nothing to do directly with any test comparing group means. Many box plots show more, but box plots do not usually show means at all. Here the implication is that the original data are all integers. In particular, the truncated display for Group A presumably means that more than 25% got 5, but there was no higher value, so that is at once the maximum and the upper quartile. Histograms side by side are much more informative than box plots for a few integer values.

Answer (score 1):

The
[documentation of the `cld()`
function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/multcomp/versions/1.4-17/topics/cld)
refers to [Piepho (2004)](https://doi.org/10.1198/1061860043515), but
even more on point in this context is

> **[Piepho,
> Hans-Peter](https://www.uni-hohenheim.de/organisation?tx_base_lsfcontentadmin%5BlsfPerson%5D=6257&L=1)
> (2018) Letters in Mean Comparisons: What They Do and Don’t Mean**,
>
>  Agronomy Journal, 110(2), 431-434. DOI:
> [10.2134/agronj2017.10.0580](https://doi.org/10.2134/agronj2017.10.0580)
> [(ResearchGate)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/322054734_Letters_in_Mean_Comparisons_What_They_Do_and_Don%27t_Mean)
>
> **Abstract**
>
> - Letter displays allow efficient reporting of pairwise treatment
>   comparisons.
> - It is important to correctly convey the meaning of letters in
>   captions to tables and graphs displaying treatment means.
> - The meaning of a letter display can and should be stated in a
>   single sentence without ambiguity.
>
> Letter displays are often used to report results of all pairwise
> comparisons among treatment means in comparative experiments. In
> captions to tables and charts using such letter displays, it is
> crucial to explain properly what the letters mean. In this paper I
> explain what the letters mean and how this meaning can be succinctly
> conveyed in a single sentence without ambiguity. This is contrasted to
> counter-examples commonly found in publications.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mean
```

Group 1  4.7  A
Group 2  5.9  AB
Group 3  7.8   B

Means with the same letter are not significantly different (by some test that you name). Thus the only significant difference is between Group 1 and Group 3. You also provide the significance level, usually 0.05, but other options are sometimes used.